# Spring 3 binding objects to form in jsp view

Tags: java, spring, forms, jsp

I am trying to bind an object to my form and submit that to my controller.

My initial request to get the form view will attach objects to my model to be rendered in my view.

Adding the attributes in my controller:

```
model.addAttribute("objects", getObjects());
model.addAttribute("form", newForm());
```

My form is quite simple:

```
public class Form {
    private List<Object> objects;
    private List<String> results;

    // getter and setters
}
```

In my .jsp I list the objects and have input fields for the results:

```
<form:form id="form" action="${formURL}" method="POST" commandName="form">

    <c:forEach items="${objects}" var="object" varStatus="vs">
        /* bind object to list of objects in form */

        <label>${object.name}</label>
        <form:input path="results[${vs.index}]"/>
    </c:forEach>

</form:form>
```

When posting the form to my controller I can successfully retrieve all the results, what I'm missing is the original list of objects.

Is there a way to bind each object to my List of objects to be retrieved in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

Either   Use Hidden fields on JSP/HTML.
Or  Use HTTP Session  to    hold original results.